# Encoding IOB format, entity nested inside other entity

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a dataset and I have to do named entity recognition with it. I would convert the dataset which is a json to IOB format but i have an issue:
The dataset contains entity nested in other entity, for example

Sentence:

```
Traitement des manifestations neurologiques progressives des patients adultes et des enfants atteints de maladie de Niemann-Pick type C
```

Entity:

```
"manifestations neurologiques progressives des patients  atteints de maladie de Niemann-Pick type C"    and     "adultes"    and    "enfants"
```

How should I encode the bigger one with nested entity inside?

I thought about:

| word | tag |
| --- | --- |
| Traitement | O |
| des | O |
| manifestations | B-Cible |
| neurologiques | I-Cible |
| progressives | I-Cible |
| des | I-Cible |
| patients | I-Cible |
| adultes | B-Caracteristique_du_sujet |
| et | O |
| des | O |
| enfants | B-Caracteristique_du_sujet |
| atteints | I-Cible |
| de | I-Cible |
| maladie | I-Cible |
| de | I-Cible |
| Niemann-Pick | I-Cible |
| type | I-Cible |
| C | I-Cible |

But i'm not sure it's correct and comprehensible for an algorithm then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either take just the outermost layer and use that as NER training data, or you can use all your labels to create spans (including nested spans) and train a [span categorizer](https://spacy.io/api/spancategorizer/). You might also want to look at the [spancat example project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/experimental/ner_spancat_compare).

You can't represent nested spans with IOB format, so if you go that route, you'll need to manually create Doc objects with spans saved in `Doc.spans`.